# Regular expression for a string of two parts separated by dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regular expression for a string of two parts which is separated by '.' Here below are the condition,

1. <<1st part>>.<<2nd part>> : Example- Time01.Sheet
2. 1st part should contain alpha numeric characters and it must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabet, 1 lowercase alphabet, and 1 number.
3. 2nd part should contain alpha numeric characters.

**My code** : `((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=\\S+$).*)[.]([\\w]+)$`

**Input** : `Vijay.hello876IUY`

**Actual Output** : `Valid data`

**Expected Output** : Invalid data (Because 1st part doesn’t contain any numbers)

Any one please help me to solve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=[^.]*[a-z])(?=[^.]*[A-Z])(?=[^.]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPhEAS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^.]*[a-z])` - there must be a lowercase ASCII letter after 0+ chars other than `.`
- `(?=[^.]*[A-Z])` - there must be an uppercase ASCII letter after 0+ chars other than `.`
- `(?=[^.]*[0-9])` - there must be a digit after 0+ chars other than `.`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

In Java:

```
s.matches("(?=[^.]*[a-z])(?=[^.]*[A-Z])(?=[^.]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

Since `matches()` requires a full string match, you need no `^` at the beginning and `$` anchor at the end.